# Eloquent: Paginate Two Query Result With Different Condition (Has different with())

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Hello fellow Laravel programmer.

---

I'm on Laravel 5.7 and I'm having 4 tables:

`outlets` - belongsTo `merchants`, also belongsToMany `promos`

`promos` - belongsTo `merchants`, also belongsToMany `outlets`

`merchants` - list of merchants that has many promos (hasMany `promos`, hasMany `outlets`)

`outlet_promo` - that connects `outlets` and `promos`, only store their IDs

---

### Condition 1#:

Every merchant's promo that only active in specific outlet has `outlet_promo` values, such as

```
outlet_promo
outlet_id      promo_id
    1             1
```

Means that the `promo_id` 1 only active on `outlet_id` 1.

### Condition 2#:

Now if a promo active on all merchant's outlets means that no relation on `outlet_promo`. (I'm avoiding too many storing in `outlet_promo` table)

### Fetching Data

I'm trying to get all `outlets` where has active `promos` that can be `active in some outlets only` and `active in all outlets`, resulting me in this two query:

1. Getting all `outlets` where has active promos and its promo available in **every outlets**

```php
$outlets_all = Outlet::with(['merchant.promos' => function ($q) {
            $q->doesntHave('outlets');
        }])->whereHas('merchant.promos', function ($q) {
            $q->whereDate('start_date', '<=',  date('Y-m-d'));
        })->doesntHave('promos.outlets');
```

2. Getting all `outlets` where has active promos and its promo only active in **selected outlets**

```php
$outlets_selected = Outlet::with(['merchant.promos' => function ($q) {
            $q->has('outlets');
        }])->whereHas('promos', function ($q) {
            $q->whereDate('start_date', '<=',  date('Y-m-d'));
        });
```

**The key difference is in `with` condition**

### Goals

Within these two queries I managed to get the desired output. But now the goal is I want to **paginate** both result in one object so I can lazy load the `outlets` on the view using AJAX. I want to display list of `outlets` that has `promos` (all outlets or selected outlets) with list of active `promos` that outlet has.

### What I have tried so far

I tried to `union()` and `unionAll()` both queries, resulting correct outlets, but has wrong `promos` list from `merchant.promos`. It seems that the union operation messes up the promos. Every merchant's promos seems have same value, when actually they should be different.

I even tried to merge the query with two `with()` operation like this:

```php
$merge = Outlet::with(['merchant.promos' => function ($q) {
            $q->has('outlets');
        }], ['merchant.promos' => function ($q) {
            $q->doesntHave('outlets');
        }])->whereHas('promos', function ($q) {
            $q->whereDate('start_date', '<=',  date('Y-m-d'));
        })->orWhereHas('merchant.promos', function ($q) {
            $q->whereDate('start_date', '<=',  date('Y-m-d'));
        })->doesntHave('promos.outlets');
```

And it just results the same as the `union` I did before.

I'll be tremendously grateful for any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the answer myself.

I end up simplize the query by splitting into two query where

First, I get all of the outlets with both of my conditions.

Second, I loop through all the result then I select each active promos in each outlets.

So in this case I'm avoiding double `with()` on my query.

Thank you.